# is "I am scary" sentence right or wrong?

Tags: word-choice

Ok, *scary* = *frightening* (source: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Ascary)

And we often hear "*it is frightening*" and "*I am frightened because of frightening movie*", but we never say "*I am frightening*".

SO, I think "*it is scary*" is correct while "*I am scary*" is incorrect. But why googling "*I am scary*" shows like 28000 results (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22i+am+scary%22).

So, is "*I am scary*" sentence right or wrong?

Comment: If you're dressed up like Dracula, it's reasonable to say "I am scary".

Comment: Feasibly this might be an acceptable question on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but I'm closevoting for lack of prior research. It's Too Basic for ELU.

Comment: 'I am purple.' is grammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is the sentence, "I am scary", right or wrong?

It is correct. It is a valid, meaningful grammatical sentence in English.

The person in the following picture could justifiably say the words, "I am scary."

[image]

Comment: wow, that's is a very scarily informative answer. After reading your answer, I think I will remember how to use "scary" forever

Answer (score 0):

In that case you are telling me that there are at least some that in general are somewhat afraid of you. You may tell what aspect I need to have some respect for like 'I am a scary driver'.

Answer (score 0):

"I am scary" means that I frighten people; "I am scared" means I, myself am frightened.  However, there is a song "Plastic Jesus" by George Cromarty and Ed Rush, popularized in the 1967 film *Cool Hand Luke*:

> I don't care if it rains or freezes
>  Long as I got my plastic
>   Jesus
>  Sittin' on the dashboard of my car.
> ...
>  Goin'
>   ninety, **I ain't scary**
>  'Cause I got the Virgin Mary
>  Assuring me
>   that I won't go to hell.

It's clear that the meaning is "I ain't scared," and just as clear that the rhyme requires "scary."  I don't know whether there's a southern (US) colloquialism behind it or not, but it shows up in rap music with the same meaning.  Perhaps it's an elision of "scaredy" ("scared" + "-y"), which mostly appears in "scaredy-cat," one easily frightened.